# Openmp shared variables clause

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

If I declare a variable int n=5 inside main and above #pragma omp parallel , then it's a shared by all threads inside parallel region so my question is where this n variable is stored and how threads can access it , what is the mechanism behind it?

Is n is stored on heap? Or in stack of main or in some other region.? Please explain

Comment: AFAIK this is not described by the OpenMP specification so each OpenMP implementation can do it differently (there is not only one implementation). In practice, the pointer of the variable is stored and saved to a runtime data structure. The compiler can then remap the variable in the target function. This means reading `n` dereference a pointer `p`, and `p` contains the address of (the shared) `n`. An OpenMP implementation can store this information in the stack though I am not sure most implementation do that. You should not rely on this in your program (since it is not specified).

Comment: If you want to know more about that for a specific implementation, then you should specify the target implementation used. GCC uses GOMP by default. Clang uses IOMP. AFAIK, ICC uses a modified version of IOMP. MSVC can either use IOMP (new) or its own historical implementation (old & obsolete). Research runtime or HPC stack can provide custom implementation (often compatible with either GCC or Clang/ICC).

Comment: That means pointer to shared variable has been stored in stack of each thread? Via pointer , threads can access this shared variable?

Comment: AFAIK it is a block of allocated memory containing pointers to shared variables (and other runtime information like possibly private variables) which is then sent to each threads so they can have a pointer to this block in their stack and then access the right variable. The compiler can theoretically generate a code accessing the pointer of the shared variable since it can know the location of each variable in the block. But again, all of this is very dependent of the target implementation (though I remember GOMP and IOMP work a bit like that -- IDK for the compiler part still).

Comment: But, overall, yes : the shared pointers enable threads to read/write the same shared variable in memory. I advise you to pick an implementation and look the code. The one of GOMP (GCC) is not so difficult to read and not so big either (compared to IOMP).

Answer (score 3):

As @Jérôme-Richard says, this is not specified by the OpenMP(r) standard. However, at least LLVM (so most vendor compilers now), and GCC allocate a local variable on the stack, even if it is later shared.

You can see this in code like [compiler explorer example](https://godbolt.org/z/x57hdGMjf), which counts the number of threads that are created by an undecorated `omp parallel`. (Of course there are many simpler ways to do this, but it makes a relatively small, comprehensible, example to look at).

```
    int availableThreads()
    {
        int s = 0;  
    
        #pragma omp parallel shared(s)
        {
            #pragma omp atomic
            s += 1;
        }
        return s;
    }
```

Consider the (annotated) LLVM generated code :-

```
availableThreads:                       # @availableThreads
        push    rax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], 0 # Allocate s on the stack and zero it
        lea     rdi, [rip + .L__unnamed_1]
        lea     rdx, [rip + availableThreads.omp_outlined]
        lea     rcx, [rsp + 4] # Pass the address of s in rcx
        mov     esi, 1
        xor     eax, eax
        call    __kmpc_fork_call@PLT
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        pop     rcx
        ret

availableThreads.omp_outlined:          # @availableThreads.omp_outlined
        lock            inc     dword ptr [rdx]
        ret

.L__unnamed_2:
        .asciz  ";/app/example.c;availableThreads;6;5;;"

.L__unnamed_1:
        .long   0                               # 0x0
        .long   2                               # 0x2
        .long   0                               # 0x0
        .long   38                              # 0x26
        .quad   .L__unnamed_2
```

We can see `s` being allocated and zeroed in the outer function, and the its address being passed into the OpenMP runtime fork function. In the outlined parallel body (`availableThreads.omp_outlined`) we can see that value being passed in by the runtime as the only argument, and the target of the pointer being incremented atomically.

The GCC code is similar (play with the Compiler Explorer example if you want to see it, or see what happens on other architectures).